# I'm successfully connected to server and to database, but I tried testing POST Request with Postman but all I get is {} with status 400 (Bad request)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

Here is my user schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
email:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
password:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
tokens:[
    {
        token: {
            type:String,
            required:true
        }
    }
]
})
```

I'm using jsonwebtoken to hash password before saving and tokens to verify users
And here is my registration route

```
app.post('/register', async (req,res)=>{
try{
    const username=req.body.username;
    const email=req.body.email;
    const password=req.body.password;

    const createUser= new Users({
         username:username,
         email:email,
         password:password
    });
    const created=await createUser.save();
    console.log(created);
    res.status(200).send("Registered");
    } catch(error){
      res.status(400).send(error);
    }
    })
```

When I type this into Postman

```
{
"username":"John Smith",
"email":"JohnSmith@gmail.com",
"password":"password123"
}
```

I get {} with status 400 (Bad request)

Comment: Did you set your request body to Raw with JSON?

Comment: Yes I did, doesn't work

Comment: Did you set a body-parser middleware?